# Mobile site commenting min char limit not shown

Tags: bug, user-interface, mobile-web

I was replying to an answer with a comment. However Add Comment was not working (but it was enabled), clicking on it was void. Later on I figured out I needed a few more characters to submit the comment. However mobile UI does not show a message or indicator, that's not good.